# What's the shortcut for mesh menu?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, shortcut

I'm referring this menu:

[image]

It's weird that Face, Edge, Vertex and even Add menu all have their own shortcuts, but Mesh doesn't have one. I searched "Mesh" in preference, but even weirder yet, that "Mesh" there is actually "Add" menu.

Comment: It is like it is... so what's your question? How to create a shortcut for the mesh menu? Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no default keyboard shortcut for accessing the Mesh menu, nor does there appear to be any way to point to that function when going into *User Preferences*, then under *Keymap*, and trying to create a custom shortcut for it. I'd love it if someone could show me that there is a way.

The absolute simplest way to solve your problem would be to right click on the Mesh menu tab itself, and from the popup dialog, choose **Add to Quick Favorites**. Then, whenever you press <kbd>q</kbd> to bring up your *Quick Favorites* menu, the *Mesh* menu will be available to select any time you like, without needing to hunt for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to selecting a vert, edge, or face (by way of the <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, or <kbd>3</kbd> keys respectively), the key you would use for selecting the entire mesh is <kbd>l</kbd> (short for "**l**inked"). This will select the entire mesh that is connected to whatever your mouse is hovering over.

Comment: That's not what the OP is referring to. The reason the OP is referencing terms such as "Face", "Edge", "Vertex" etc., is because if you go into Edit Mode, there are actual menus for those things at the top of the 3D View, and they can be independently accessed with a click. The OP is telling us that there are shortcuts available for accessing those menus, but NO shortcut for accessing the Mesh menu. Which is true.

Comment: @R-800 Thank you very much. Finally someone understands my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new hotkey through *Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Mesh > Mesh (Global)*, then scroll to end of list and click *Add New*.

Expand the *None*. In the field type `wm.call_menu` then a name field should show up type `VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh`.

Then in the key field (Default is <kbd>A</kbd>) click it and then press the hotkey you want to use. To find out if a key is free you can enable the is key free addon that comes with Blender. Then in text editor press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or click *View > Sidebar* check box. Then click *Dev* tab, enter key you want to use and click magnifying glass icon. In this case you want to look for 3D view and mesh to see if your hotkey is used.